# SQL Server MERGE statement in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert, sql-merge

```
merge into Mytable WITH (HOLDLOCK) as dst
                    using (select @mId as MId,  
                        @up as UP, 
                        @termsAccepted as TermsAccepted, 
                        @AnalyticsAccepted as AnalyticsAccepted, 
                        @EssentialCookiesPolicyWasAccepted as EssentialAccepted,

                    ) as src on dst.MId = src.MId and dst.UP = src.UP
                when matched then 
                    update set dst.TermsAccepted = src.TermsAccepted,
                        dst.AnalyticsAccepted = src.AnalyticsAccepted,
                        dst.EssentialAccepted = src.EssentialAccepted,

                when not matched then
                    insert(MId, UP ) 
                    values(src.MId, src.UP)
```

Trying to convert this into postgres but cant seem to find a reason syntax replacement for merge?

tried a recursive query but slightly lost on how deep to go?

```
WITH f AS (
select mId as MId,  
up as UP, 
) as src on dst.MId = src.MId and dst.UP = src.UP
)
INSERT INTO myTable (MId, UP) 
SELECT src.MId, src.UP
FROM src
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
insert(MId, UP ) 
values(src.MId, src.UP)
```

Comment: Good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql) on how Postgres 9.5+ "INSERT ON CONFLICT (key) DO UPDATE...` Insert syntax that should work as a replacement to `MERGE` in sql server.

Comment: thanks, I have used insert into but I cannot seem to understand the recursion part of it. still working o nit

Comment: I don't think there is any need for recursion here. You are upserting/merging from one table/result-set into another table based on a key. Whether thats `UPSERT`, `MERGE`, `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY...` `INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT...` it's more or less a sql syntax question.

Comment: im not too sure what you mean, could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the Microsoft SQL server statement does exactly, but you can try something like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mid, up) VALUES ($1, $2)
ON CONFLICT (mid, up)
DO UPDATE SET mid = EXCLUDED.mid, up = EXCLUDED.up;
```

This requires a unique constraint on `(mid, up)`.

The columns in the `UPDATE` branch in your question have different names, but that doesn't make any sense to me. Replace details as necessary!

Comment: apologies, bit of incorrect copy and past there. fixed with correct columbs added

Comment: Ok, makes sense now. Just use the actual column names instead of the ones in my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

The `MERGE` command is available as of Postgres 15.

[MERGE documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-merge.html)